# Having Issues with isotope filtering in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2, jquery-isotope

I am working with a free responsive web template that I have edited to make a small portfolio site for a friend. The issue that I am having is that when I choose a specific image gallery and view in the Fancybox window, it will continue to click through all of the images, and not just the ones in that specific gallery.

I have been searching and found this solution (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/ncVsViD2v9o), but I don't really have a knowledge of javascript so I'm unsure if this would work for me or how to implement it into the template's code. I've included a portion of the html and what I believe is the related js below:

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Portfolio Projects -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">
    <!-- Filter -->
    <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
      <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
        <li class="type-work">Photography</li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Images</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".people">People</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".places">Places</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".things">Things</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Filter -->
  </div>

  <div class="span9">
    <div class="row">
      <section id="projects">
        <ul id="thumbs">

          <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
          <li class="item-thumbs span3 people">
            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="John" href="_include/img/work/full/people-01-full.jpg">
              <span class="overlay-img"></span>
              <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/people-01.jpg" alt="Print Number 1–10">
          </li>
          <!-- End Item Project -->

          <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
          <li class="item-thumbs span3 things">
            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Garden Wall" href="_include/img/work/full/things-07-full.jpg">
              <span class="overlay-img"></span>
              <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/things-07.jpg" alt="Print Number 1–22">
          </li>
          <!-- End Item Project -->
```

**JS**

```js
BRUSHED.filter = function() {
  if ($('#projects').length > 0) {
    var $container = $('#projects');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
      $container.isotope({
        // options
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        itemSelector: '.item-thumbs',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      });
    });


    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        return false;
      }
      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
      var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
      // parse 'false' as false boolean
      value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
      options[key] = value;
      if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
        // changes in layout modes need extra logic
        changeLayoutMode($this, options)
      } else {
        // otherwise, apply new options
        $container.isotope(options);
      }

      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if I need to give anymore information.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dave, I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provided. Do you have a live link? One thing I see is that you have to give different names to each "galleries" for Fancybox. Try `data-fancybox-group="gallery-01"` and `data-fancybox-group="gallery-02"` and so on.

Comment: Hi Louys, thanks for getting back to me. This is the current test version of the site: http://www.susanemiller.com/brushed/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your live link was really helpfull to try something.
Nice presentation, by the way.

So... The solution to your issue was, like I said in comments yesterday, to change the `data-fancybox-group` attribute... And you have to do it on click of a category link.

The pictures IN the selected category must NOT be in the FancyBox group "gallery"... But in a "selected" gallery. Only pictures with the same gallery name as the one that was clicked to trigger FancyBox will then be displayed.

Here is the code I added:

```
// find the clicked category
var fancyBoxClassToShow = $(this).attr("data-option-value");

// reset all data-fancybox-group (in case of a previous selection)
$("#thumbs").find(".item-thumbs").each(function(){
  $(this).find("a").attr("data-fancybox-group","gallery")
});

// change all data-fancybox-group that IS a child of the clicked category
$("#thumbs").find(fancyBoxClassToShow).each(function(){
  $(this).find("a").attr("data-fancybox-group","gallerySelected")
});
```

I added only these lines in your `$optionLinks.click` function, right above `var $this = $(this);`.

And that's it.
See [**CodePen here**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NRgRqQ?editors=1011).

Comment: Awesome! I can't thank you enough for your help Louys!

Comment: Was a pleasure! You have a nice project for this photographer, I noticed the clean code ;)